# Lazy Image Loader to ListView

Tags: android, listview

Well, I used this project as start point to my project:
https://github.com/thest1/LazyList/

Instead of his LazyAdapter I used one that i made, following:

```
public class CardAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Card> {
    private Card[] cards;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater; 
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 


    public CardAdapter (Context context, int textViewResourcesId, Card[] cards)
    {
        super(context, textViewResourcesId, cards);
        this.cards = cards;
        this.context = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);  
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {  
        public ImageView iconView;  
        public TextView nameTextView;  
        public TextView descText;
        public TextView manaText;
        public TextView atkdef;
        public TextView edicao;
        public TextView tipo;
    }  

    @Override  
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {  
        ViewHolder holder;  
        if (convertView == null) {  
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listrow, parent, false); 
        TextView nameTextView = (TextView) convertView  
                    .findViewById(R.id.Nome);  
            TextView descText = (TextView) convertView  
                    .findViewById(R.id.descricao);  
            TextView manaText = (TextView) convertView  
                    .findViewById(R.id.mana);
            TextView atkdef = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.atkdef);
            TextView edicao = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.edicao);
            TextView tipo = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tipo);
            ImageView iconView = (ImageView) convertView  
                    .findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.nameTextView = nameTextView;
            holder.descText = descText;
            holder.manaText = manaText;
            holder.atkdef = atkdef;
            holder.edicao = edicao;
            holder.tipo = tipo;
            holder.iconView = iconView;  
            holder.iconView.setTag(cards[position].URL);

            convertView.setTag(holder);  
        } else {  
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();  
        }  

        holder.nameTextView.setText(cards[position].name);                                          holder.descText.setText(setSpanOnText(cards[position].descricao),BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        holder.manaText.setText(setSpanOnManaText(cards[position].mana), BufferType.SPANNABLE);
        if (cards[position].tipo.toLowerCase().contains("creature"))
            holder.atkdef.setText(cards[position].power + "/" + cards[position].toughness);
        else
            holder.atkdef.setText("");
        holder.edicao.setText("Edition: " + cards[position].edicao);
        holder.tipo.setText(cards[position].tipo); 
        holder.iconView.setTag(cards[position].URL);  
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(cards[position].URL, holder.iconView);
        return convertView;  
    }  
}
```

It was working well, til the moment I added "imageLoader.DisplayImage(cards[position].URL, holder.iconView);" which is the lazy load part, it started to crash when i try to access the listview, someone have something in mind? I didnt change a bit in the ImageLoader/FileCache/MemoryCache/Utils from the other project...

Thanks in advice!

Comment: it started to crash,Then Put your Logcat?

Comment: please put your error log here

Comment: thats awkward, i closed and reopened and it worked without any changes, seems like the resource was somekind bugged and needed to reload to work

Answer (score 0):

I've used this lazy-loader code before, and it's trying to access your sdcard, so make sure you set the correct permissions in your manifest.

Also, you shouldn't be accessing the ListView, just the ImageView corresponding to the tag. Are you sure you're doing it correctly? You may need to post the code using this class.

The proper way of using it in a ListView is to:

```
imageView.setTag(image_url);
imageLoader.DisplayImage(image_url, imageView);
```

in that order.

Comment: Exactly, holder.iconView.setTag(cards[position].URL);  
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(cards[position].URL, holder.iconView);

Comment: I have both permissions, to access SD and INTERNET... still dont work

Comment: in your code, you're separating the setTag and displayImage calls. try doing it like how i suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.jaapp;

    import java.util.ArrayList;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.widget.ListView;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import com.jaapp.application.JaappApplication;
    import com.jaapp.db.Jaappdb;
    import com.jaapp.dto.SubtypeDto;
    import com.jaapp.lazyloader.ImageLoader;

    public class SubTypeActivity extends Activity {

        ArrayList<SubtypeDto> arrylistsubtype = new ArrayList<SubtypeDto>();
        ListView list;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.subtype);
            new subtypeAsyncTask().execute();

        }

        public class subtypeAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
            private ProgressDialog progrssdilaog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {

                progrssdilaog = ProgressDialog.show(SubTypeActivity.this,
                        "Please wait", "Loading Data ...", true);

            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

                arrylistsubtype = Jaappdb.getSubtypeDtos();

                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

                progrssdilaog.dismiss();

                list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                list.setAdapter(new Listadatper(SubTypeActivity.this,
                        arrylistsubtype));

            }

        }

        public class Listadatper extends BaseAdapter {
            private Activity activity;

            public ImageLoader imageLoader;

            ArrayList<SubtypeDto> mlist;

            public int[] selected;
            public int countcolor = 0;

            public int i = 0;
            public String[] Colorname = { "#FFFF00", "#ACCC00" };

            public Listadatper(SubTypeActivity secondActivity,
                    ArrayList<SubtypeDto> arrylistsubtype) {

                this.activity = secondActivity;
                mlist = arrylistsubtype;

                selected = new int[mlist.size()];

                for (int i = 0; i < mlist.size(); i++) {
                    selected[i] = 0;
                }

            }

            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

                View gridView;

                gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

                TextView txt_name = (TextView) gridView
                        .findViewById(R.id.txt_entrepreneur);

                ImageView img_icon = (ImageView) gridView
                        .findViewById(R.id.img_entrepreneur);
                txt_name.setText(mlist.get(position).getName());

                imageLoader = new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
                imageLoader.DisplayImage(getString(R.string.imagelink) + mlist.get(position).getLogo(), activity, img_icon);
                if(position % 2 == 0) {
                    gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Colorname[0]));
                } else {
                    gridView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(Colorname[1]));
                }

                gridView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        Intent i = new Intent(SubTypeActivity.this,
                                SubOptionTypeActivity.class);
                        JaappApplication.subtypeid = mlist.get(position).getId();
                        startActivity(i);

                    }
                });

                return gridView;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return mlist.size();
            }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return 0;
            }

        }

    }


    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    package com.jaapp.lazyloader;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.util.HashMap;
    import java.util.Stack;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.graphics.Bitmap;
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
    import android.widget.ImageView;

    import com.jaapp.R;


    public class ImageLoader {

        private HashMap<String, Bitmap> cache=new HashMap<String, Bitmap>();

        private File cacheDir;

        public ImageLoader(Context context){

            photoLoaderThread.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY-1);


            if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
                cacheDir=new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"LazyList");
            else
                cacheDir=context.getCacheDir();
            if(!cacheDir.exists())
                cacheDir.mkdirs();
        }

        final int stub_id=R.drawable.stub;
        public void DisplayImage(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
        {
            if(cache.containsKey(url))
                imageView.setImageBitmap(cache.get(url));
            else
            {
                queuePhoto(url, activity, imageView);
                imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }    
        }

        private void queuePhoto(String url, Activity activity, ImageView imageView)
        {
             photosQueue.Clean(imageView);
            PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
            synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                photosQueue.photosToLoad.push(p);
                photosQueue.photosToLoad.notifyAll();
            }

            if(photoLoaderThread.getState()==Thread.State.NEW)
                photoLoaderThread.start();
        }

        private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
        {

            String filename=String.valueOf(url.hashCode());
            File f=new File(cacheDir, filename);

            //from SD cache
            Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
            if(b!=null)
                return b;

            //from web
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap=null;
                InputStream is=new URL(url).openStream();
                OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
                Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
                os.close();
                bitmap = decodeFile(f);
                return bitmap;
            } catch (Exception ex){
               ex.printStackTrace();
               return null;
            }
        }

        //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
        private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
            try {
                //decode image size
                BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

                //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
                final int REQUIRED_SIZE=70;
                int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
                int scale=1;
                while(true){
                    if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                        break;
                    width_tmp/=2;
                    height_tmp/=2;
                    scale++;
                }

                //decode with inSampleSize
                BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                o2.inSampleSize=scale;
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
            return null;
        }

        //Task for the queue
        private class PhotoToLoad
        {
            public String url;
            public ImageView imageView;
            public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
                url=u; 
                imageView=i;
            }
        }

        PhotosQueue photosQueue=new PhotosQueue();

        public void stopThread()
        {
            photoLoaderThread.interrupt();
        }

        //stores list of photos to download
        class PhotosQueue
        {
            private Stack<PhotoToLoad> photosToLoad=new Stack<PhotoToLoad>();

            //removes all instances of this ImageView
            public void Clean(ImageView image)
            {
                for(int j=0 ;j<photosToLoad.size();){
                    if(photosToLoad.get(j).imageView==image)
                        photosToLoad.remove(j);
                    else
                        ++j;
                }
            }
        }

        class PhotosLoader extends Thread {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while(true)
                    {
                        //thread waits until there are any images to load in the queue
                        if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()==0)
                            synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                                photosQueue.photosToLoad.wait();
                            }
                        if(photosQueue.photosToLoad.size()!=0)
                        {
                            PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
                            synchronized(photosQueue.photosToLoad){
                                photoToLoad=photosQueue.photosToLoad.pop();
                            }
                            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                            cache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                            //if(((String)photoToLoad.imageView.getTag()).equals(photoToLoad.url)){
                                BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad.imageView);
                                Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
                                a.runOnUiThread(bd);
                          //  }
                        }
                        if(Thread.interrupted())
                            break;
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    //allow thread to exit
                }
            }
        }

        PhotosLoader photoLoaderThread=new PhotosLoader();

        //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
        class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
        {
            Bitmap bitmap;
            ImageView imageView;
            public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, ImageView i){bitmap=b;imageView=i;}
            public void run()
            {
                if(bitmap!=null)
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                else
                    imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
            }
        }

        public void clearCache() {
            //clear memory cache
            cache.clear();

            //clear SD cache
            File[] files=cacheDir.listFiles();
            for(File f:files)
                f.delete();
        }

    }
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    package com.jaapp.lazyloader;

    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

    public class Utils {
        public static void CopyStream(InputStream is, OutputStream os)
        {
            final int buffer_size=1024;
            try
            {
                byte[] bytes=new byte[buffer_size];
                for(;;)
                {
                  int count=is.read(bytes, 0, buffer_size);
                  if(count==-1)
                      break;
                  os.write(bytes, 0, count);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex){}
        }
    }
```